# Attempting to get data from sharepoint 2013 using C# results in HTTP 500

Tags: rest

```
        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("https://sharepointurl/_api/lists/"));
        wr.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        var v = wr.GetResponse();
```

On executing the request, I get a HTTP 500 error.

The URL returns the data successfully in IE

Any pointers as to whats wrong?

Comment: Can you do a capture or get more details regarding the response via debugging? What do your HTTP headers look like for this request?

Comment: Strange, that code snippet works for me. What if you specify the credentials:
    
    CredentialCache creds = new CredentialCache();
            creds.Add(new Uri(reqUrl), "NTLM", new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"));
    wr.Credentials = creds;

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, you are missing some required headers.  Did you look at the error message associated with the 500 code? To do that you should a program like fiddler.

Also, check out the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/apps/jj164022.aspx.  It describes out to use the 2013 REST API and documents the use of the headers you need.